# Gesture recognizer for mouse down and up in iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I want to catch both mouse down and mouse up using gesture recognizer.  However, when the mouse down is caught, mouse up is never caught.

Here's what I did:

First create a custom MouseGestureRecognizer:

```
@implementation MouseGestureRecognizer
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {  
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];  
    self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized;  
}  

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {  
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];  
    self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized;  
}  
@end
```

Then bind the recognizer to a view in view controller:

```
UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [MouseGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleGesture:)];  
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
```

When I click mouse in the view, the touchesBegan is called, but touchesEnded is never called.  Is it because of the UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized?

Comment: Mouse? What is this mouse you speak of? Surely you mean touch, touch down, and touch up.

Comment: Yes, it's actually touch up and touch down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [UIGestureRecognizer class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIGestureRecognizer/reset) for `reset` method:

> The runtime calls this method (`reset`) after
>   the gesture-recognizer state has been
>   set to UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded
>   or UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized. (...) After this
>   method is called, the runtime **ignores**
>   all remaining active touches; that is,
>   the gesture recognizer receives no
>   further updates for touches that have
>   begun but haven't ended.

So, yes, it's because you're setting the state to `UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized` in `touchesBegan`.

**EDIT**

As a workaround, you can make two recognizers, one for `touchesBegan` and the other for `touchesEnded`, and then add both of them to the target view:

```
UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer1 = [TouchDownGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleGesture:)];
UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer2 = [TouchUpGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleGesture:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:recognizer1];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:recognizer2];
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Then what should I do to solve it? If I remove UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized, then the handleGesture: will not be called.

Comment: I've tried to add two recognizers to the target view, but still got the same problem.  After the first gesture (TouchDown) is handled, the touch up is skipped.

Comment: You may need to return `YES` for the method `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer`.
Check this: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate/gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can use a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` instead with `minimumPressDuration` set to `0`.